# JQuery sum values and update a div content

Tags: jquery, checkbox, sum

I have a form with a table with textfields and adjacent checkboxes, when the checkbox is checked I need to sum the amount of the checked textfieds (amount)

the sum of the amount should be displayed in the

```
<div id="total" style="color:red">500</div>


<tr class="">
  <td style="font-size:11px; padding:3px">3795</td>
  <td style="font-size:11px; padding:3px"><input type="text" value="" size="6" name="chq_no"></td>
  <td style="font-size:11px; padding:3px"><input type="text" value="0" size="6" name="amount"></td>
  <td style="font-size:11px; padding:3px; width:20px"><input type="checkbox" value="3795" name="id"></td>
</tr>
```

this is my trial which is not working

```
var sum = 0;
      $('checkbox :checked').each(function() {
          sum +=  $(this).parents('tr:first').find('input[name="amount"]').val();
      });
      $('#total').html(sum);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly what you and @void already figured out, but here's a real stripped back version that accomplishes (I think) what you've been looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/k1xfehrq/6/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function sumRows() {
        var sum = 0,
            total = $('#total');
        $('tr').each(function () {
            var amount = $(this).find('input[name="amount"]'),
                checkbox = $(this).find('input[name="include"]');
            if (checkbox.is(':checked') && amount.val().length > 0) {
                sum += parseInt(amount.val(), 10);
            }
        });
        total.text(sum);
    }

    // calculate sum anytime checkbox is checked or amount is changed
    $('input[name="amount"], input[name="include"]').on('change keyup blur', sumRows);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

On change of checkbox, parse every `input[type=text]` fetch its value and add them up and put it in the `#total`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


        $("input[type=text], input[type=checkbox]").on("change keyup", function(){
        var sum = 0;  
        if($("input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked"))
        {
        $("input[type=text]").each(function(){
           sum += +$(this).val();
        });
        }
        $("#total").html(sum);
        });

    });
```

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/fjwek6mo/9/)**

Comment: check it here, if you remove the check from any one after checking it, the total will be 0
https://jsfiddle.net/fjwek6mo/4/

Comment: I didnt get you? If the Originally Posted Problem is solved please vote up the answer and mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: no it's not solved, please play with the checkboxes, you will find the sum is not correct

Comment: You want to refresh the sum on checkbox check or as soon as user enters the value when check box is checked?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71203/discussion-between-void-and-mohamed-badr).

Comment: yes that's what I want, updating the sum amount automatically whenever I check/uncheck the check boxes or change the amount in the textfields

Comment: See the updated answer, Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/fjwek6mo/9/. I hope this is what you want, right? If it solves your problem please consider voting it up and marking it as correct answer.

Comment: check it here with multiple rows, it will display the sum even if check box not checked   https://jsfiddle.net/fjwek6mo/14/

Comment: and it is summing all text fields, while I need it to count only the amount field

Comment: See the updated fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/fjwek6mo/22/. I hope this is what you want, right? If it solves your problem please consider voting it up and marking it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Couple thoughts:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')...
```

I'm not sure your selector will find anything. I would `console.log()` inside your `.each()` function to make sure you're getting in there.

Secondly, make sure that the value returned by `.val()` is an integer and not a string. (Perhaps use `parseInt()` to explicitly coerce it.)

Comment: @mohamed-badr, do you intend for the sum to change when the text inputs are updated (as long as the checkbox is :checked)? A little more clarity in defining the problem would likely result in a clearer solution.

Comment: I need to sum all the selected values, it's a kind of payment form, you select the items which you want to pay for, so the sum of the amount should be displayed before payment

Comment: the closest solution is here https://jsfiddle.net/fjwek6mo/4/  
however if you uncheck, the total amount is coming back to zero

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  var sum = 0;
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
     sum += +$(this).parents('tr:first').find('input[name="amount"]').val();      
  }
  $('#total').html('');
  $('#total').html(sum); 
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/de3oovL5/

Comment: it's not adding the amount(summing)

Comment: it's not adding the amount, try to add another row to the table it will not sum, it will just display the checked value

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(':checkbox').on('change', function(){
    var sum = 0;
    $(':text').each(function(){
      sum += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    });
    $("#total").html(sum);
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/kdysxgsL/)**

Comment: Did you test it in FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/kdysxgsL/ yet? I t works to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){

function checkChanged(){
    var sum = 0;
    $("input[type='checkbox']:checked")
        .each(function(index, item){
            sum+= Number($(item).parents("tr").find("input[type='text'][name='amount'][value]").val());
    });
    $("#total").html(sum);
}

    $("table").on("click", "input[type='checkbox']", checkChanged);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/someg8od/6/